# Python pandas Write dataframe to CSV in specific rows where column is equal to value

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have my algorithm and code. It works but writes the dataframe to an entire column in my output CSV file. I want to write the dataframe to only rows where the column is equal to a certain value. This is on Line 6. Rest of logic, syntax seems fine. I researched a fair few options including sort_values(), apply(), map(), lambda, writing if statements. It seems like an easy solution but I cannot get to write the dataframe to specific rows and column combination. If this question has been asked for before, please refer me to the solution.

Thank you.

## Output file - Line 1

`df_Working_File = pd.read_csv('Working\WF.csv')`

## Input File - Line 2

`df_GSTRemoved = pd.read_csv('Working\GSTRemoved.csv')`

## Concat for vlookup essentially in output file - Line 3

`df_OriginalKey = df_GSTRemoved.apply(lambda x:x['Origin'] + x['Destination'],1)`

## Concat for vlookup in input file - Line 4

`df_Key = df_Working_File.apply(lambda x:x['Origin'] + x['Destination'],1)`

## Value of column dataset to write  - Line 5

`df_Charge_Per_Item = df_GSTRemoved['500g']`

## Line 6 -  I want to write the dataframe to column 9 for all rows where Origin is GL in the input file

`df_Working_File.apply(df_Charge_Per_Item, df_Working_File['Origin'] == 'GL')`

## Line 7 - Writing to csv with no index column

`df_Working_File.to_csv("Working/writetoCSV.csv", index=False)`

Comment: Can you add sample data - 5, 6 rows with desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You can write subsets of the dataframe by using boolean vactors forexample:

```
# boolean vector:
selector = df_Working_File['Origin'] == 'GL'
# write only rows to csv where the vector is true:
df_Working_File[selector].to_csv("Working/writetoCSV.csv", index=False)
```

If you also want to write only certain columns, you can use this:

```
df_Working_File[selector][['col1', 'col2']].to_csv("Working/writetoCSV.csv", index=False)
```

Btw you can concat columns also like this:

```
df_OriginalKey = df_GSTRemoved.Origin + df_GSTRemoved.Destination
```

## edit

If you want to change/edit only rows that meet certain conditions you can do this:

```
 selector = df_Working_File['Origin'] == 'GL'
 df_Working_File.ix[selector, 'column_to_change'] = 'changed value'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for concat.

That wrote only the rows where Origin is GL and removed all other rows where Origin is not GL. I need the other Origins to be in the file and to write to only rows where Origin is GL.

# Input file
`Origin Destination Zone 500g`
`GL          N1              Sydney 7.563636364` 
`GL          GF              Gosford 7.563636364` 


#Output File Format only header is provided
`Origin Destination Charge (per item)`
`AAT, AAT, `
`GL, AAT``
`GL, N1`
`GL, GF`
`GL, WG`
`GL, NC`
`GL, CB`
The issue is that I am not able to write to the rows where Origin is GL.